# Cannot SocketListen on TCP client

Tags: socket

The following code fails to work when I try to send a message from the server to the client.

```
server = SocketOpen[Automatic];
client = SocketConnect[server];
SocketListen[client, Print];
WriteString[server["ConnectedClients"][[1]], "test"];
```

Is the `SocketListen` function not able to work on TCP socket client? Thanks